# asp.net cookie not storing value

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm setting a cookie in asp with the below snippet. When I look at my cookies in firebug I see the cookie however the value itself is blank. 
I know the `respondArray[1]` variable is a string however it's just not saving into the cookie.

```
 System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("secretKey", respondArray[1]);
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about secretKey[1] but you use respondArray[1]. Is that ok or maybe it's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be help you

```
 HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");  
        userCookie["Country"] = "Italy";  
        userCookie["City"] = "Rome";  
        userCookie["Name"] = "Jones";  


if (cookie != null)   
        {  
            string country = cookie["Country"];  
            string city = cookie["City"];  
            string name = cookie["Name"];  
            Label2.Text = "Cookie Found and read<br/>";  
            Label2.Text += "Name: " + name;  
            Label2.Text += "<br />Country: " + country;  
            Label2.Text += "<br />City: " + city;  
        }
```

Comment: I've found that setting the cookie my original way (and your way) both work as long as I don't redirect after, which is a requirement...is there an issue with redirecting and cookies I don't know about?